# How to handle https for iOS client

Tags: ios, http, https, afnetworking, digital-certificate

We know that https is different with http by encrypting the content over http tunnel, simply speaking.

For the web browser, since user accept the permission from the popup alter dialog, the browser will get the keys from installed certificates and do the job so on.

For iOS client development, how to handle the digital certificate, and get the public key and encrypt the content via the public key ? thanks,

( By the way, AFnetworking is the famous open source project for iOS developer to handle the http stuff, but seems like that it does not handle the https. (correct me if wrong ) )

Comment: (1) HTTPS doesn't encrypt "content over HTTP tunnel". It's HTTP running over previously secured channel - an opposite to what you probably imagine. (2) are you going to re-implement SSL/TLS? If no, then use some classes for HTTPS and don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

NSURLConnection and NSURLSession are the underlying classes used by all HTTP iOS libraries. These two classes does the HTTPS handling for you. Nothing for you to worry about.

Then, you can use libraries as AFNetworking or Hermod that work on top of these basic iOS classes.

- [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is the most popular one.
- [Hermod](https://github.com/mobilejazz/Hermod) is my preferred. It is a new library built on top of AFNetworking and its API is much simpler and easy to use. Also, it has built-in support for OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

It's already done for you.

[AFnetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), the underlying iOS network library it's built on, [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and pretty much every networking library (eg, [ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), etc) all handle the https protocol for you transparently.

Indeed, the very first line [on the front page of the AFNetworking github page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is an https example:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global"];
```

Comment: Thanks,seems like it is done. There is a macro _AFNETWORKING_PIN_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ , which handle the certificate. One thing still confused me that, for the browser, there will be some popup dialog to tell user if trust this certificate, and there could be some risks to access the web site. For iOS, how to handle this case ?

Comment: You would use SSL Certificate Pinning only if your App connects to a *known* server for which you have a CA certificate. You should deploy the corresponding certificate with the app - possibly in the bundle. So, there is no need to ask the user if it can trust this certificate - you (the developer) have it done already. Btw, it's never ever a good idea to ask a user if it trusts the certificate - she will choose whatever will work to connect to anything - even if the site's URL reads "attacker.com"

Comment: A word about macro AFNETWORKING_PIN_SSL_CERTIFICATES. You should rise the question on the forum whether - if the flag is defined - handles "host name verification".